# How to solve ValueError while checking rows in a particular column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get number of "NaN" values in particular column using below code. I can't use `df["column_name"].isna().sum()` because i have thousands and column and i want to check number of null values in each column. Sometimes i also need to check symbols presents in the column.

```
count=0
for col, rows in df.items():
    if col == "co2":
        if rows=="NaN":
            count=count+1
print(count)
```

Every time i run this code, i gets this ValueError saying following things.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can anyone help to find what is wrong with this code?

Comment: You should provide a representative example of your data. Using something like `df["column_name"].isna().sum()` is really the way to go. iterating rows will be very inefficient

Comment: @mozway i know that would be inefficient, time taking process but if i will have some symbols in the columns and i would like to find that symbol how do i do that. That's why i was using this approach.

Comment: Difficult to answer without a representative example ;)

Comment: Actually i'm using kaggle datasets. so if you need i can provide a link of that.

Comment: Best would be to make a minimal example in the question with the most representative cases. Then you should be able to adapt to the full case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list of all the columns you want to count the null values for and iterate over that list to find the nan counts. As an example if you want to go over all of the dataframe's columns:

```
columns = df.columns.values.tolist()
nan_count = {}
for column in columns:
    nan_count[column] = df[column].isna().sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is told you by Python. To make this code work you should amend your condition to

```
if "NaN" in list(rows):
    print("got it")
```

but it is very inefficient with large datasets. The approach you are excluding should be employed.